# how to resize the parent shell

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have created a dialog box with the below code. I need to make the shell re-sizable. How can i do that?

```
public class MyDialog extends TrayDialog {
  public MyDialog(final Shell shell) {
    super(shell);
    this.shell = shell;
}

 public MyDialog (final Shell shell, final MyData myData) {
    super(shell);
    this.shell = shell;
 }

 @Override
 protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent) {
  //code for the text/combo/button etc..go here
 }

}
```

from another class i call it like this

```
final MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog (new Shell(), myData);
    if (myDialog .open() == Window.CANCEL) {

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the `Dialog.isResizable` method is the preferred method of setting the `SWT.RESIZE` style:

```
@Override
protected boolean isResizable()
{
  return true;
}
```

From the JavDoc:

> Returns a boolean indicating whether the dialog should be considered
>   resizable when the shell style is initially set. This method is used
>   to ensure that all style bits appropriate for resizable dialogs are
>   added to the shell style. Individual dialogs may always set the shell
>   style to ensure that a dialog is resizable, but using this method
>   ensures that resizable dialogs will be created with the same set of
>   style bits. Style bits will never be removed based on the return value
>   of this method. For example, if a dialog returns false, but also sets
>   a style bit for a SWT.RESIZE border, the style bit will be honored.

Comment: thank you..this worked....one more Question..how do i add/enable scroll bar to this shell

Comment: You need to ask that as a new question.

Comment: done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387199/how-to-enable-scroll-bar-on-a-shell

Answer (score 1):

Give the Shell the [appropriate style](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html), SWT.RESIZE, when you create it.